# How to unmock an object in jest-extended?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm currently mocking the Azure cosmos Container and ContainerResponse for my unit tests. I'm mocking using jest-extended, https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended. I'm comparing the expected result against a mocked result object, but I would like the result object to be an actual object. If I create a dummy ContainerResponse object, it has a lot of readonly and private properties that I'm not able to set, so I'm trying to mock it with my implementation, then unmock it.

Here is my test:

```
test('this should return the container from initializing the database', async () => 
{
    const containerId = "testContainer";
    const expectedResult = {container : {id: containerId} };
    const result = await initializeContainer(containerId);
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

Here is my jest mock for CosmosClient:

```
export class CosmosClient 
{
    readonly endpoint: string;
    readonly key: string | undefined;
    readonly databases: Databases;
    readonly containers: Containers;

    constructor(options: CosmosClientOptions)
    {
        this.endpoint = options.endpoint;
        this.key = options.key;
        this.databases = mock<Databases>();
        this.containers = mock<Containers>();
        
        this.containers.createIfNotExists = async (containerRequest) => 
        {
            const container = mock<Container>({id: containerRequest.id});
            return mock<ContainerResponse>({container}); 
        };
        this.databases.createIfNotExists = async (dbRequest) => 
        {
            const db = mock<Database>({id: dbRequest.id, containers: this.containers });
            return mock<DatabaseResponse>({database : db});
        };
    }
}
```

The initialize container function is shown below:
(The new CosmosClient calls my mocked version instead)

```
export async function initializeContainer(containerId: string)
{
    const { endpoint, key, databaseId } = config;
    try
    {
        const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint ,key});
        const containerDefinition = getContainerDefinition(containerId);
        const db = await createDatabase(client, databaseId);
        const createdContainer = await createContainer(db, containerDefinition);
        return {container: createdContainer};
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        console.log(err);
        return{container: undefined};
    }
}
```

Here is the createContainer function that ends up returning the main result:

```
export async function createContainer(database: Database, containerDefinition: ContainerDefinition)
{
    const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists(containerDefinition);
    console.log(`Created container ${container.id}`);
    return container;   
}
```

database.containers.createIfNotExists(containerDefinition) returns the mocked container in the CosmosClient mock object. In C# there's a way to access the mocked objects implementation using mock.object. Is there a jest-extended equivalent? Here is the result from my unit test to illustrate what I'm talking about.

```
  - Expected  - 0
    + Received  + 4

      Object {
        "container": Object {
    +     "_isMockObject": true,
    +     "asymmetricMatch": [Function mockConstructor],
          "id": "testContainer",
    +     "nodeType": [Function mockConstructor],
    +     Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): [Function mockConstructor],
        },
      }
```

Comment: Could you just use `expect(result).toMatchObject(expectedResult);`? [toMatchObject](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject)

Comment: That was it, thank you! If you make it the answer, I'll mark it.